# Unable to see KPI in Browser View Visual Studio SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio, kpi

i'm unable to see the kpi i defined in visual studio. 
In form view the KPI is there and is correct (just constant numbers).

[image]

In Browser view I cannot see it... 
[image]

I Expected to be able to see the kpi with its gauge in this tab.
Can someone please help me.

thank you

Comment: I've got the same problem. Which version of VS are you using? I am on 2017.